# Adding Description to MapQuest Flash API Mobile

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile, mapquest

Basic code:

```
protected function map_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
  this.geocoder = new Geocoder(this.map.tileMap);
  this.geocoder.addEventListener(GeocoderEvent.GEOCODE_ERROR_EVENT,this.onGeocodeError);
  this.geocoder.addEventListener(GeocoderEvent.REVERSE_GEOCODE_RESPONSE,this.onReverseGeocodeResponse);
  this.geocoder.addEventListener(GeocoderEvent.HTTP_ERROR_EVENT,this.onHttpError);

  cursorManager.setBusyCursor();
  this.map.removeShapes();
  var ll:LatLng = new LatLng(Number('40.053097'), Number('-76.313652'));
  this.geocoder.reverseGeocode(ll);
}

private function onGeocodeError(e:GeocoderEvent):void 
{
  // trace the error..
}

private function onHttpError(e:GeocoderEvent):void 
{
    this.cursorManager.removeBusyCursor();
    this.makeErrorList("HTTP ERROR");
}

private function onReverseGeocodeResponse(event:GeocoderEvent):void 
{
    // Add the descriptive name to the locationg being geocoded.
}
```

On the on onReverseGeocodeResponse event, how can I add a descriptive label to the location tooltip so that when the user focuses on the location pointed, it will show that label which I added, including the complete address that the map service locates?

Is there also a way that I could add a button on the location tooltip, so that when the button is clicked, I could perform other functions?

Comment: I found the answer to this and it is by using Points of Interests (POIs) instead of GeoCoding. I will post the answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Points of Interest was the property that was needed to be modified.